# Computer wont go to sleep?

Tags: windows-vista, sleep

I have a media computer with Windows Vista Home Premium. When I activate media sharing, the computer refuses to go to sleep after x-minutes of idling. If I turn of the media sharing the computer will go to sleep by itself. Is it supposed to behave this way when media sharing is activated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by design.

When you enable media sharing you are instructing your machine to always be on. Therefore the ability to enter sleep is disabled, as the machine should **always be** available for others to access the shared media. However if you do want it to go to sleep follow these steps:

> - Start the Power Options Control Panel applet (Start, Control Panel, Power Settings).
> - Select the "Change plan settings" option for the current power plan.
> - On the settings dialog box, click the "Change advanced power settings."
> - Scroll down to the "Multimedia settings" option and expand the "When sharing media."
> - Change the setting to "Allow the computer to sleep.
> - Click OK, then close all open dialog boxes.
> - The "Allow the computer to enter Away Mode" is the setting Media Center enables.
>
> The away mode functionality makes the computer appear to be off to the user but actually keeps the system running.

From [here](http://thewinforums.com/topic/6019-it-cant-enter-sleep-mode-while-sharing-media-in-on/)

Answer (score 1):

See this [tutorial](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/63567-power-options-sleep-mode-problems.html) and make sure that the "Multimedia Settings" for "When sharing media" is set to "Set to Allow the computer to sleep".

Comment: +1 For beating me by 5 seconds. I *just* had to look for the settings.

Comment: Time is money, man! BTW I returned the +1 compliment.